# How do you package/publish a Visual Studio Mac console application, that can run on a windows machine?

Tags: macos, visual-studio, console-application, publish

This is the first time I've written a console application on the Mac version of Visual Studios. Normally, on Windows I just build the project and zip everything in the \bin\Release folder. When I publish the project to a folder on the Mac, it generates a .dll, .pdb, and 2 .json files. I want to package this and send it to a user to run on their Windows machine. I'm not sure where the .exe is. Honestly, don't know if a Mac would even generate that type of extension.

So, how do you package/publish a Visual Studio Mac console application, that can run on a windows machine? Are the .json files intended to execute from a browser?

Comment: It seems that you created a .NET Core console app on Mac. .NET Core is completely different from .NET Framework (what you described on Windows), so you have to study from scratch, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/deploy-with-cli

Comment: Thanks "dotnet publish -c Release -r win-x64 -p:PublishReadyToRun=false" did the trick. It created a ton of .dll files, but I guess that is why it can be self-contained. edit: I don't have a way to accept your answer, I can only respond to it.